# Introducing yourself in Japanese when you have a Roman name?

Tags: names, rōmaji, transcription

While reading online, I found numerous websites that had "Romaji translations" of names that use the Roman alphabet. For example, the Japanese version of Jordan is said to be either Jo-dan or Yorudan. So how do introduce myself? "Watashi no namae wa Jordan desu" or "watashi no namae wa Jo-dan/Yorudan desu?"

Comment: How do you pronounce your name in your native tongue?

Comment: @broccoliforest JOR-den, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Roman alphabet, you can either leave it as original spelling, or convert it to rōmaji (= in Japanese pronunciation).

If you go with original spelling, you'll be fine at that point, but may face a "So, how do you pronounce it after all?" afterwards.

If you choose rōmaji, you should transcribe it according to **the sound in your language, instead of spelling**. Fortunately, [transcription from English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_into_Japanese) has been very predictable: *Jordan* always becomes *jōdan* (ジョーダン). What you found *yorudan* (ヨルダン) is for the name of [Kingdom of Jordan](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3), or of those from Germany and other Central European countries, where they pronounce the letters that way.